# Get all the data with specific tag in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, tags, laravel-5.3

I am using **eloquent relationships** for `post` and `tags` through `post_tags`. What i'm trying to do is make sections of `posts` in my front-end view with specific `tags`. Like if i have a section `1` it should have all posts of tag `"new"`, section `2` should have all posts of tag `"old"` etc. And i want all of this to happen in a same view.

**Post Model**

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tag');
}
```

**Tag Model**

```
 public function posts()
 {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_tag');
 }
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('frontend.index')->withPosts($posts);    
}
```

Please help me out:)

Comment: You stil get the error `Undefined variable: tags` ??

Comment: @Maraboc yep.. i've also updated my question

Comment: Can you add the view code ??

Comment: Right now in my view i am only showing posts like foreach ($posts as $post) <h3>{{ $posts->title }}</h3> endforeach. But i dont know how to get post of specific tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the tags with loading the posts :

```
public function index()
{
    $tags = Tag::with('posts')->get();
    return view('frontend.index')->withTags($tags);    
}
```

In the view you can do something like this :

```
@foreach ($tags as $tag)
    <h2>Tag : {{ $tag->name }}</h2>
    @foreach ($tag->posts as $post)
        <p>Post : {{ $post->title }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

---

For geting the posts where you have a tag :

```
public function index()
{
    $tagName = 'new';
    $posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use($tagName) {
        $q->where('name', $tagName);
    })->get();
    return view('frontend.index')->withTagName($tagName)->withPosts($posts);
}
```

And in the view you can do this :

```
<h2>Tag : {{ $tagName }}</h2>
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <p>Post : {{ $post->title }}</p>
@endforeach
```

If you want to do queries from view you can do it like this (*but it's not a god practice because the view is just for viewing the content not geting it from database*) :

```
<?php foreach ((\App\Post::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use($tagName) {
                    $q->where('name', $tagName);
                })->get()) as $post) { ?>

            <p>Post : {{ $post->title }}</p>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Hussyn is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: No sir, i'm looking for something like $posts = Post::with('tags)->where('name', '=', 'new')->get();

Comment: it works :D Thank you.. :) But can we use it with foreach because in ruby on rails i can do something like posts.joins(:tags).where('tags.name = ?', 'new').each do |post| it will gave me the same answer but i dont know how to do it in laravel

Comment: i didn't get what you want exactly can you explain it more ?

Comment: means can we apply this in our view side and it still get the same answer like foreach ($posts->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use($tagName) {
        $q->where('name', $tagName);
    }) as $post)

Comment: I updated the answer but as i said it's not a good thing to do beause you didn't respect the MVC pattern ;)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

To get all posts with tags with name `new`, do this:

```
Post::whereHas('tags', function ($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'new');
})->get();
```

Comment: i think sir you didn't understand my question. i'm trying to get all the post with the tag name 'new'. i think your code will display all the tags of one post.

Comment: @HussynNaqvi thanks for the explanation, I've updated my answer.

Comment: now i get error "Undefined variable: tags". And secondly will this code work with foreach loop in my view?

Comment: @HussynNaqvi you've said you just want to get Posts where Tag name is "new". If you also want to load tags, add `->with('tags')` to the query and use foreach loop from my previous answer.

Comment: i've said in my question that in my frontend view i want different sections of tags. In those section i want specific posts of specific tags like in section 1 i want all posts of tags 'new' in same time on another section i want all posts of tag 'old' etc and all of this happening in a same view of same controller.

Answer (score 0):

It is solution not perfect answer
You can handle this situation in two ways

```
1- send two objects from controller to view seprate one for only new tag and second without new tag
```

2- you can handle this situation in front-end by using conditions

```
@if($user->tag == "new")
{$user->show}
@endif
```